# Mock an ad preview on iOS and Android on a web app built with Angular 5

Tags: android, ios, angular

I am developing an Angular 5 application which is supposed to be used by advertisers to create advertisements to be displayed on a host of different mobile devices. The client is now asking for a preview screen for a 3.5 inch smartphone screen on Android and iOS.

Do you have any ideas how to render real time images just uploaded in a preview mode for both iOS and Android - either as a separate page or as a modal - within a desktop app?

Is there any JavaScript framework that can help with the default screens and layouts for both of these devices?

Anything better than a resized iframe?

Comment: What are Android and iOS profiles ? What kind of application do you have ? Are you using a framework ? Otherwise, what is your issue ? Please read [ask] a question

Comment: @trichetriche - I am unable to find a way to display the advertisement images and links on the Angular UI - looking exactly the way it would look like on a 3.5 inch smartphone screen. I do not have the buttons, fonts, and other native elements to make it look original.  My question is - is there any framework that can help me achieve this preview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my comment : I don't have knowledge of a framework that can do that.

But it's pretty easy to mock. All you need is to display a div that has the size of the phone screen you're targeting.

You won't need much code and browser compatibility since you only want to display an image and some text. I'm pretty sure all browsers can handle that.

A quick search for the iPhoneX gave me the dimensions 2.436 x 1.125

Given the size, let's take a third of this : 812 x 375

Now I don't know the buttons on iPhone so I won't display them, but here is a mock of an iPhoneX screen :

```css
#screen {
  height: 821px;
  width: 375px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
}

#img-ad {
  height: 80%;
  background: teal;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#txt-ad {
  height: 20%;
  background: tomato;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="screen">
  <div id="img-ad"><span>80% of screen</span></div>
  <div id="txt-ad">Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit Amet, and I only remember this part</div>
</div>
```